# Error: read ECONNRESET at TLSWrap.onStreamRead

Tags: javascript, node.js, sendgrid, api-key

I am trying to send an email in my nodejs app using @sendgrid/email library but when I try to send an email I am getting the following error:

> { Error: read ECONNRESET
>       at `TLSWrap.onStreamRead` (internal/stream_base_commons.js:111:27) errno: 'ECONNRESET', code: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' }

---

I tried the following code please have a look.

```
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey('***************************'); // API KEY
sgMail.send({
  to: email,
  from: 's*****@gmail.com',
  subject: 'signup succeeded!',
  html: '<h1>You Successfully Signed Up!</h1>'
})
```

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are behind proxy.
This error occurs when your sending machine is not able to connect to sendgrid api server.